# How can I apply customRanking to slaves in Python

Tags: python, algolia

In my Django algolia settings I want to add slaves with specific sorting, for example

```
   settings = {
       'attributesToIndex': index_fields,
       'slaves': ['Book_by_price_asc','Book_by_price_desc'],
   }
```

but I can't seem to find the proper way to add a customRanking to the slaves

`'customRanking': ['asc(book)'] and 'customRanking': ['desc(book)']`.

I would like to be able to define it in python similar to what [algolia rails](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rails#multiple-sort-criteria) support.

```
add_slave 'Book_by_price_asc', per_environment: true do
  attributesToIndex [:name, :author, :editor]
  customRanking ['asc(price)']
end
```

Is this possible in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, that's not available in the Django integration yet.